# hosting multiple directories with same port using sub URL directories

Tags: apache-2.2

If I have a site hosted on port 8080, so

http: //mysite:8080

and I have 3 components to the site I'd like to access from that port,

http: //mysite:8080/cms, http: //mysite:8080/statistics, http: //mysite.com:8080/foo

how would I set that up using Apache, so that each (cms/statistics/foo) point to different directories in my Linux server?

(had to add spaces after http: cause I'm new and can't include links)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create three directories under the apache root directory. For example, you can create:

```
/var/www/cms
/var/www/statistics
/var/www/foo
```

Assuming the apache root is `/var/www/`.

Comment: There are more complicated scenarios, but this depends on your needs.

Comment: how can i setup a virtual host at that point? if i set up 3 parallel ones, it will only assign the last <VirtualHost *:8080> to port 8080

Comment: If you want to setup virtual hosts, you can see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/ip-based.html